# need jquery & litte html css improvement on Owl Slideshow With Tab Navigation(pagination)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i just make a skelenton & makeup  owl slideshow with tab navigation . **i need jquery to rotate slide with text navigation . any one can help with it that would be appricible.**

Reference demo : http://www.suprafootwear.com/

[this is what i end with html and css using my local server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNq8x.png)

**i also want some portability on code like less divs and also position & overflow issues too .**

i have little mess with full width slideshow that would shown in **refercence demo** 
so suggest me and correct me with better solution so i can apply to my computer and run with proud : )

```js
  jQuery('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
 items: 1,
 center: true,
 margin: 0,
 callbacks: false, 
 autoplayHoverPause: true, 
 loop: true,
 autoplay: true,
 autoplayTimeout: timer,
 URLhashListener: false,
 startPosition: 0,
 responsiveClass:true,
 responsive:{
    0:{    
     dots: true,
     stopOnHover: true,
    },
    770:{   
     nav: false,
     dots: false, 
     onChange: selectTab,
    }
   }
 
  });
```

```css
body {
 font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
 background: #fff;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #333;
}
.container
{
 width:100%;
 max-width:1024px;
 position:relative;
 background-color:#f39c12;
 height:auto;

}
section{
 display:block;
}
.c-slider #tab-container {
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 max-width:960px;
 height:auto;
}
.c-slider #tab-container span {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 22.9995%;
margin-bottom:10px;
padding:10px 0;
text-align: center;
font-size: 12px;
text-transform: uppercase;
border-right: #ccc 1px solid;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-family: 'corporate_condensed', sans-serif; 
margin:5px;
}
.c-slider #tab-container a:nth-of-type(4) span 
{
border-right: 0; 
}

.c-slider #tab-container a, .c-slider #tab-container a:hover, .c-slider #tab-container a:active, .c-slider #tab-container a:visited
 {
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: #000;
cursor: pointer;
 }
.c-slider #tab-container span:hover 
{
color: #fff;
background: #444; 
}
.c-slider #tab-container span.active 
{
color: #fff;
background: #444;
opacity:0.5; 
}
.c-slider #tab-container a span.active, .c-slider #tab-container a:hover span.active, .c-slider #tab-container a:active span.active, .c-slider #tab-container a:visited span.active 
{
color: #fff; 
}
.c-slider #slider_time {
  display: none; 
}
.demo-6 .ow-slider-wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
.demo-6 .bg-img {
 padding: 200px;
 box-sizing: content-box;
 position: absolute;
 top: -200px;
 left: -200px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>FullWidthOwl Slider</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.suprafootwear.com/skin/frontend/rwd/supra/css/owl/owl.carousel.min.css">
 </head>
<body>
<div class="container demo-6">
 <div id="slider" class="ow-slider-wrapper">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-loaded owl-drag">
          <div class="owl-item">
             <div class="item">
              <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/1.jpg" alt="">
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="owl-item">
           <div class="item">
            <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/2.jpg" alt="">
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="owl-item">
             <div class="item">
              <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/3.jpg" alt="">
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="owl-item">
             <div class="item">
              <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/4.jpg" alt="">
              <div class="owl-nav disabled">
     <div class="owl-prev">prev</div>
     <div class="owl-next">next</div>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-dots disabled"></div>
             </div>
          </div>

    </div>
 </div>
 **<section class="c-slider">
  <div id="tab-container">
   <a><span class="">TextOne</span></a>
   <a><span class="">TextTwo</span></a>
   <a><span class="">TextThree</span></a>
   <a><span class="">TextFour</span></a>
  </div>
   <span id="slider_time">5000</span>
   <div style="clear:both"></div>
 </section>**
</div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.suprafootwear.com/skin/frontend/rwd/supra/js/owl/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle I can help you with that

Comment: yeah i just making it now once finished i post here on your comment

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Kaash/7zhmd3ju/  i just create help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your tabs like this and add the js code
https://jsfiddle.net/jorge182/7zhmd3ju/1/

```
<a><span id="1" class="">TextOne</span></a>
<a><span id="2" class="">TextTwo</span></a>
<a><span id="3" class="">TextThree</span></a>
<a><span id="4" class="">TextFour</span></a>

 $('span').on('click', function(){
    var element = this.id;
  $('.owl-carousel').trigger("to.owl.carousel",element);
});
```

Comment: thanks for you post can  you make with this using tab

Comment: tried but click event not perform well. as no effect at end. thanks for your code. if u can manage to improve futher with working demo that would be nice

Comment: I have a problem wit jsfiddle, the scripts owl are not loading

Comment: hmm ok. u can set up this demo on your local server(local host) and make it alive then send me code and suggestion to do that with my computer

Comment: hi how are you ? check out my question : Owl-Slideshow : Image fit issue and Hightlight tab on image rotate  . i have posted whole jquery code and click event works fine. all i need to do is now to high light that tab with image associate with it.check when soon rply

Comment: I have the solution, i was working with old owl library. Check the jsfiddle again.

Comment: wow buddy its working really charm. and its portable code to easily understand. many thanks : ). also can make auto rotate that when image rotate it automatically highlight text tab.